# How can i make my clock update with my runTime function?

Tags: javascript, html, algorithm, web-applications

I'm working on a small digital clock project that is supposed to mimic a real clock by using a power button to turn the clock on and display the current time, and to also power off the clock and have the display render as empty. that is what the project is supposed to do, but right now it is doing that. It does render current time as inner text into the display the first time the button is clicked but does not update with the setInterval function i am using. Only the console prints current Time along with the update. can i get some help with my code please? I have some notes on the project if something is not clear please ask kindly thanks. I want to find out why when i want to power off does the clock not turn off and why my time is not updating on the display like i want it too. I have some code below to illustrate what i tried to write.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>Document</title>

    <style>
        #digital-clock {
            border: 2px solid black;
            height: 200px;
            position: relative;
            width: 400px;
        }
        #display {
            border : 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 9px;
            font-size: 40px;
            height: 55px;
            line-height: 55px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 15px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 250px;
        }

        #button {
            border: 2px solid black;
            border-radius: 50%;
            font-size: 16px;
            height: 55px;
            line-height: 55px;
            position: absolute;
            top: 10px;
            left: 305px;
            text-align: center;
            width: 55px;
        }


    </style>
</head>
<body>

    <div id="display"></div>
    <div id="button">OFF</div>
</body>
<script language="javascript" type"text/javascript" src="digtalclock.js"></script>
</html>

var c_d = document.getElementById("display");
var btn = document.getElementById("button");
console.log(btn)
console.log(c_d);

function setTime() {
    var d = new Date();//current date and time. 
    var h = d.getHours();//the current hours.
    var m = d.getMinutes();//the current minutes.
    var s = d.getSeconds();//the current seconds.
    var ct = `${h}:${m}:${s}`; // a var called ct short for clocktime which does the same as h +":"+ m +":"+s
    console.log(ct);//ct logs current time and updates occordingly when page is refreshed.
    runTime(ct);// callBack for runTime with ct as parament value. 
}
function runTime(x) {
    var t = x;//var ct passed in as parameter from setTime function and stored as data into variable t in runTime().
    console.log(t);//t is still console logging ct the variable data.
    var n = 0;//used for tracking clicks 
    console.log(n);
    btn.addEventListener("click",function(e) {//click toggle function. 
        n += 1;// increments by 1 everytiime click executes. 
        var c = setInterval(setTime,1000);//a setInterval statement which is supposed make time tick but only on the console. not on display like i want to. 
        console.log(n);
        const s = ["ON ","OFF"," ",];
        //*************NOTES REGARDING THE IF STATEMENT*****************
        //**************************************************************
        /*odd and even numbers are used to keep track of the click event.
        the if statement is used to detect even numbers. Inside the body 
        i used the constant string variable s which has 3 strings indexed
        and combine that with click button event to create a toggle effect 
        indicating when the power is on the else statement is read because 
        when you click the button the first number to appear is odd, and 
        since n increments by one the following number is 2 and even. So the 
        if statements states if n is even when you click the button the text 
        inside is changed by grabbing one of the 3 indexed items of const s array. 
        the power button excutes as off and the dispay is supposed to go blank 
        by using an empty string that is indexed inside the cost s variable. */
        if(n % 2 === 0)  {
            console.log("Even Num");
            btn.innerHTML = s[1];
            c_d.innerHTML = s[2];
            c = clearInterval(c);
        } 
        //**************NOTES REGARDING THE ELSE STATEMENT*******************
        /*The purpose of the else statment is. Since we are treating the project
        as if it were a real life clock with on and off power buttons. when n and btn 
        interact for the first time it console.logs 1 meaning our first odd number is 
        created. and n is incremented by one. since n starts with a value of 0. its logical to 
        say that if you click the button 1 is added to n everytime. furthermore, i use n to keep
        track of the clicks . Since were powering on the clock the inner text of the 
        button will use cost s variale and and the first indexed item to idicate the power 
        is on. for the clock display or the section where you see time apear at i used the 
        c_d var name short for clock_display and passed it a method of innerHTML = to t because
        i thought i finally invoked the set interval function but time is not updating. it 
        is only displaying current time at the point of click as innerHTML. while it updates on the console. 
        nothing updates on the display.*/
        else{
            console.log("odd num");
            btn.innerHTML = s[0];
            c_d.innerHTML = t;
        }
    });
}
setTime();
```

Comment: setTime calls runTime, which adds a click Event Listener, when clicked, this calls setTime every second ... which adds even more click Event listeners ... that's the first problem you'll have to fix

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
  <title>test</title>

</head>
<body>
  <div>Time <span id="time">00:00:00</span> </div>
  <div><button id="btn">Power off</button></div>
  <div><button id="on">Power On</button></div>

  <script>

      var btn = document.getElementById("btn");
      var on = document.getElementById("on");
      var timestamp = new Date();

      var interval = 1;
      var flag = 0;
      var mytimer = setInterval(function () {
          timestamp = new Date(timestamp.getTime() + interval * 1000);
          btn.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            flag = 1
          })
          on.addEventListener("click",function(e) {
            flag = 0
          })
          if(flag == 0)
          document.getElementById('time').innerHTML =  timestamp.getHours() + 'h:' + timestamp.getMinutes() + 'm:' + timestamp.getSeconds() + 's';
          else
          document.getElementById('time').innerHTML = '0h: 0m: 0s';
      }, Math.abs(interval) * 1000);



  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Try it. Here two button power on and power off